# How to Get Google Forms Data in an Email Message?

Tags: forms

I am using Google form to track lead from my landing page.
I am also able to get notification on when someone fill the form. But I want to get actual data of inquiry other than just notification.
I have tried using [this code](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/S0n7WjjSIhs)

But its not working I guess. Need someone can guide me step by step here. I am totally new here. All experts please respond.

Thanks,

Edit: I already found the answer for this quesion.

Comment: Please could you be more specific than "it's not working".

Comment: Hi Danial, I have found the solution. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution.

1. Click to spreadsheet >> Tools > Script Editor >> Paste following script.

```html
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{
 
  var email = "youremail@gmail.com";
  
  var txt = "";
  for(var field in e.namedValues) {
    txt += field + ' :: ' + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n";
  }
  
  MailApp.sendEmail (email, "Your Subject goes here ", txt);
}
```

2. Save the code >> Resource > Current Projects Triggers >> Rename Project with whatever you want >> Click on No trigger set up. click here to add now. >> Select Events from spreadsheet >> On Form Submit >> Save.
3. It will prompt to authorize. Do it as it will require. >> Save.

Tips:

- If you want to send email to 2 or more different emails just add more
  email ids in "youremail@gmail.com, youremail1@gmail.com" You can also
  change subject line for whatever you want.

Comment: When you are allowed to, please accept your own answer.

Comment: @krisdestruction I didnt get you.

Comment: Since you answered your own question and got it to work, you should mark your own answer as the "accepted answer".

Comment: It gives following error:-
TypeError: Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined. (line 7, file "Code")